# How do I fill up the page grid and that the content widths are laid out in a single column?

Tags: html, css

**I'm trying to learn the basics of CSS code to create flex box columns for web development. However, all I managed to do is produce one column of flex boxes. What are some basic CSS codes that would verify that the div cards always fill up the page grid and that for a width small enough, the contents are laid out in a single column?? The first section of code is in HTML. The second section is in CSS. Should I have created a second class for the div card?**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <!--
  HTML Code  
   -->
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Coding Challenge 5-2</title>
<link href="code5-2_layout.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
<link href="code5-2_flex.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

   <h1>Social Media Sites</h1>

   <section>
      <div class="card">
         <header><h1>Facebook</h1></header>
         <img src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook" class="icon" />         
         <footer>238,150 followers</footer>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
         <header><h1>Twitter</h1></header>
         <img src="twitter.png" alt="Twitter" class="icon" />         
         <footer>48,871 followers</footer>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
         <header><h1>Instagram</h1></header>
         <img src="instagram.png" alt="Instagram" class="icon" />         
         <footer>171,244 followers</footer>
      </div> 
      <div class="card">
         <header><h1>GooglePlus</h1></header>
         <img src="google-plus.png" alt="GooglePlus" class="icon" />         
         <footer>64,288 followers</footer>
      </div> 
      <div class="card">
         <header><h1>YouTube</h1></header>
         <img src="youtube.png" alt="YouTube" class="icon" />         
         <footer>Subscribe to our Channel</footer>
      </div> 
      <div class="card">
         <header><h1>Vimeo</h1></header>
         <img src="vimeo.png" alt="Vimeo" class="icon" />         
         <footer>Get the Vimeo Feed</footer>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
         <header><h1>Skype</h1></header>
         <img src="share.png" alt="Skype" class="icon" />         
         <footer>Join a Skype Chat</footer>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
         <header><h1>Pinterest</h1></header>
         <img src="pinterest.png" alt="Pinterest" class="icon" />         
         <footer>Create your Page</footer>
      </div> 
      <div class="card">
         <header><h1>Bloggr</h1></header>
         <img src="bloggr.png" alt="Bloggr" class="icon" />         
         <footer>Subscribe to our Feed</footer>
      </div> 
      <div class="card">
         <header><h1>Tumblr</h1></header>
         <img src="tumblr.png" alt="Tumblr" class="icon" />         
         <footer>Get Daily Updates</footer>
      </div>  
      <div class="card">
         <header><h1>Share</h1></header>
         <img src="share.png" alt="Share" class="icon" />         
         <footer>Share our Content</footer>
      </div>  
      <div class="card">
         <header><h1>E-mail</h1></header>
         <img src="email.png" alt="email" class="icon" />         
         <footer>E-mail Us!</footer>
      </div>        
   </section>
</body>
</html>

    @charset "utf-8";

/*
  CSS Code
*/

section {
    display: flexbox;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}

div.card {
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: 200px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to wrap your css inside `<style></style>` tag to make it work.
Secondly, `Flexbox` is preferable for single-dimensional use. But you can work around to achieve your goal pretty easily.

```
<section>
    <div class="row">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    ...
    </div>
</section>
```

You can, then, set each `row` to `display: flex` if you want it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that's what you want

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <!--
  HTML Code  
   -->
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Coding Challenge 5-2</title>
<link href="code5-2_layout.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
<link href="code5-2_flex.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<style>
    section {
    display: flexbox;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}

div.card {
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: 200px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.row
{
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0 20%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;

}
</style>

</head>
<body>

   <h1>Social Media Sites</h1>

   <section>
       <div class="row">
        <div>
            <header><h1>Facebook</h1></header>
            <img src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook" class="icon" />         
            <footer>238,150 followers</footer>
         </div>
         <div>
            <header><h1>Twitter</h1></header>
            <img src="twitter.png" alt="Twitter" class="icon" />         
            <footer>48,871 followers</footer>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
        <div>
            <header><h1>Facebook</h1></header>
            <img src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook" class="icon" />         
            <footer>238,150 followers</footer>
         </div>
         <div>
            <header><h1>Twitter</h1></header>
            <img src="twitter.png" alt="Twitter" class="icon" />         
            <footer>48,871 followers</footer>
         </div>
       </div>
   </section>
</body>
</html>
```